# incompatible types: View cannot be converted to LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

When I want to make Apk file I get 8 errors, I hope someone helps me to fix it

> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   C:\Codes\code\app\src\main\java\com\insta\followers\TagsActivity.java:61: error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to LinearLayout
>           unitBanner = findViewById(R.id.unitads);
>                                    ^
>   C:\Codes\code\app\src\main\java\com\insta\followers\HelpActivity.java:32: error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to LinearLayout
>           unitBanner = findViewById(R.id.unitads);
>                                    ^
>   C:\Codes\instagram hashTags\app\src\main\java\com\insta\followers\MainActivity.java:57: error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to LinearLayout
>           unitBanner = findViewById(R.id.unitads);
>                                    ^
>   C:\Codes\code\app\src\main\java\com\insta\followers\MainActivity.java:109: error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to LinearLayout
>           rate = findViewById(R.id.rate);
>                              ^
>   C:\Codes\code\app\src\main\java\com\insta\followers\MainActivity.java:110: error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to LinearLayout
>           share = findViewById(R.id.share);
>                               ^
>   C:\Codes\code\app\src\main\java\com\insta\followers\MainActivity.java:111: error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to LinearLayout
>           settings = findViewById(R.id.settings);
>                                  ^
>   C:\Codes\code\app\src\main\java\com\insta\followers\SettingsActivity.java:58: error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to LinearLayout
>           unitBanner = findViewById(R.id.unitads);
>                                    ^
>   C:\Codes\code\app\src\main\java\com\insta\followers\Splash.java:50: error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Button
>           start = findViewById(R.id.start);
>                               ^
>   8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s

Comment: Can you add more code so we can analyze it?

Comment: Check that `R.id.unitads` is actually a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

your are initializing your widget (button , linearlayout, .... ) with incompatible variable , you need to cast them to the right widget type , i guess you are initializing your widgets this way :

```
Button start = findViewById(R.id.start) ;
```

and you should do this :

```
Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start) ;
```

the way you are doing it is wrong , but you can use them if you are using `buildToolsVersion 26` or higher